# javascript access db

Tags: javascript, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to open a local access db on a client with:

```
try {
  var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var stcn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Dean\temp\file.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
}
catch(err) {
  alert('errors: ' + err.Message);
}
```

but I get an `undefined` error result.

Any ideas?

Comment: by "local" - I take it you mean... will never, ever be put on any sort of public Internet or (Intranet) server... correct?

Comment: I believe, this should be `err.message` as well as in browsers' javascript.

Comment: I believe the path to the data source has to be forward slashes, not backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes:

You wrote:

```
var stcn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Dean\temp\file.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
```

Must be:

```
var stcn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Dean\\temp\\file.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
```

Comment: either way, forward or escaped, it still give me the undefined error when i try to open the connection.

Comment: I also see a quick message about the activex object but it disappeares just as wuickly.

Comment: var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Dean\\temp\\lockheed_conversion.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
        try {
            cn.Open(strConn);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.Message);
        }